# debug onoutofmemory unable to start tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, tomcat8

I have the option to restart tomcat on outofmemory.

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/tomcat/bin/restart.sh
```

Here is the restart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill -9 -f tomcat
/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Tomcat executes the script , kills the tomcat, but doesn't start it back again. Here is the log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/opt/tomcat/bin/restart.sh"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "/opt/tomcat/bin/restart.sh"...
```

Please help me debug why tomcat doesn't restart.

Comment: I am not sure why some one would vote - close without reading it properly. Sort of dumb. Seems like tomcat executes the script and sits there. If I manually run the script, it totally, works  fine

Comment: Is -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError supposed to be a JVM or a Tomcat option? Google returns no results.

Comment: If the script is run in a subprocess it might be killed along with tomcat. You can add some echo lines before and after the kill to test this assumption.

Comment: @M.leRutte See [Java HotSpot VM Command-Line Options - Other -XX Options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html#CHDHGIDJ)

Comment: @M.leRutte . Yes thats a java option .

Comment: @Henry Let me add the  echo and try it out.

Comment: @Henry It still didnt help. The log end's here in tomcat catalina.out .    
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
    # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/opt/tomcat/bin/restart.sh" 
    #   Executing /bin/sh -c "/opt/tomcat/bin/restart.sh"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did'nt find an answer for this question, but I ended up running a health check on tomcat every 2 minutes which solved my problem of manually restarting tomcat whenever it is out of memory.